# LWJGL & Slick2D 64 bit

Tags: java, 64-bit, lwjgl, slick2d, pixelformat

I'm trying to compile a program in LWJGL and Slick2D using 64 bit JDK 8u60. However, when I don't put the natives in it says it's missing lwjgl64. Once I import the lwjgl64.dll natives, there is a runtime error stating that my pixel format is not accelerated. I have read other sources and people have said that I need to install newer drivers. However, I have checked for new updates and don't have any. When using the 32 bit JDK 8u60 there is no runtime error and no need to specify natives. Can someone help me fix this? I would prefer to not have to install JDK 8u60 32 bit install instead of 64 bit.

Here's my code

```
package dungeon.main;

import org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.BasicGame;
import org.newdawn.slick.GameContainer;
import org.newdawn.slick.Graphics;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class Main extends BasicGame {
private static int width = 1200;
private static int height = 800;
private static boolean fullscreen = false;
private static int targetFramerate = 120;
private static boolean showFramerate = true;
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        AppGameContainer appGameContainer = new AppGameContainer(new Main("Dungeon")); 
        appGameContainer.setDisplayMode(width, height, fullscreen); 
        appGameContainer.setTargetFrameRate(targetFramerate); 
        appGameContainer.setShowFPS(showFramerate); 
        appGameContainer.start(); 
    } catch (SlickException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
public Main(String title) {
    super(title);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}
@Override
public void init(GameContainer arg0) throws SlickException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void update(GameContainer arg0, int arg1) throws SlickException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
@Override
public void render(GameContainer arg0, Graphics arg1) throws SlickException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
}
```

Here's the error

```
Tue Oct 06 09:03:57 EDT 2015 INFO:Slick Build #237
Tue Oct 06 09:03:57 EDT 2015 INFO:LWJGL Version: 2.9.2
Tue Oct 06 09:03:57 EDT 2015 INFO:OriginalDisplayMode: 1600 x 900 x 32 @60Hz
Tue Oct 06 09:03:57 EDT 2015 INFO:TargetDisplayMode: 1200 x 800 x 0 @0Hz
Tue Oct 06 09:03:57 EDT 2015 ERROR:Pixel format not accelerated
org.lwjgl.LWJGLException: Pixel format not accelerated
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.nChoosePixelFormat(Native Method)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsPeerInfo.choosePixelFormat(WindowsPeerInfo.java:52)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.WindowsDisplay.createWindow(WindowsDisplay.java:253)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.createWindow(Display.java:306)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:848)
    at org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.create(Display.java:757)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.tryCreateDisplay(AppGameContainer.java:302)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.access$000(AppGameContainer.java:34)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer$2.run(AppGameContainer.java:367)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:348)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:317)
    at dungeon.main.Main.main(Main.java:21)
org.newdawn.slick.SlickException: Failed to initialise the LWJGL display
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.setup(AppGameContainer.java:378)
    at org.newdawn.slick.AppGameContainer.start(AppGameContainer.java:317)
    at dungeon.main.Main.main(Main.java:21)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your doing it another way than this one try to set natives by those lines

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath", new File(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"), "native"), LWJGLUtil.getPlatformName()).getAbsolutePath());
System.setProperty("net.java.games.input.librarypath", System.getProperty("org.lwjgl.librarypath"));
```

And then paste natives into /yourgamefolder/natives/windows/...

To run lwjgl even when "Pixel format not accelerated" you can turn on software mode.

```
System.setProperty("org.lwjgl.opengl.Display.allowSoftwareOpenGL", "true");
```

(however software rendering is very slow)

Comment: I tried your input method to set the natives with code and that did not work and resulted in the same error as before. Software rendering did work but unfortunately that's not what I'm looking for. I need hardware rendering with 64 bit JDK

Comment: I'm using 64bit JDK 7 and everything works fine. Check it again with java 7. If you keep getting this problem it will be related to natives libs

Comment: Here lwjgl natives which works for me with slick http://www.speedyshare.com/s9NWR/native.zip

Comment: Alright, I'll try your natives. However, my point is that I should be able to use JDK 8 64 bit. But I can't and I don't know why

Comment: It's still not working. Perhaps it's just that lwjgl and slick2D are not updated enough to use JDK 8.

Comment: I don't think problem is related to JDK 8. For test I run one of slick2d examples with JDK 8 64bit(1.8.0_60) and everything works very well.

Comment: Okay, so what do you supposed the problem is? Should I just do a fresh install of JDK, and grab a new copy of slick2d?

Comment: I tried to download a new copy and of slick2d and uninstalled/reinstalled JDK 8 64 bit and it still does not work. Using software rendering is **not** an option. @Unlox